# Overlay geom_line within a categorical x axis for each group - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I want to make a plot like this:
[image: My dream box + line plot]

The boxes would represent the distribution of a continuous variable within groups; the red circles are the points showing all of the actual observations. So far, so good. This would be simple with `geom_boxplot` + `geom_point` with a group aesthetic.

Here are the two twists:

1. The horizontal position of the points are **not** a random jitter. They are instead an X-Y coordinate utilizing a continuous X axis instead of a categorical axis
2. The line is a trendline that is fit on those points.

Some context:
This plot is showing usage of a product (Y axis) vs allowed usage (X). The X axis groups are mutually exclusive, discrete tiers on what is essentially an infinite, continuous variable for usage. EG, 1-4, 5-9, 10-20, etc. It doesn't feel crazy to me from a visual standpoint to plot the continuous within those groups, does that make sense? But I have no idea how I'd get started on getting `ggplot2` to agree with me.

*My preference is to have the box plots be evenly spaced along the X axis, but if I need to start with the axis as continuous, and have the groups take up proportionate space on the X axis then I would settle for that (likely with a logged axis to prevent the lower, narrow groups from being completely smushed*.

This should work as sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(usage = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 98L, 9L, 
                               4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L), allowed = c(2, 20, 
                                                                                        3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10, 5, 7, 12, 2, 5, 23, 10, 5, 2), id = c(1055L, 
                                                                                                                                                          2155L, 6637L, 11068L, 2070L, 8524L, 9157L, 5963L, 7593L, 3470L, 
                                                                                                                                                          3557L, 7469L, 9142L, 408L, 9446L, 1552L, 4788L, 7233L, 8464L, 
                                                                                                                                                          2188L), group = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                                                                                                                                                                            "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I came up with for you:

```
# you had some values that were = 98 in usage and throwing everything off..
df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(usage < 50)

p <- 
ggplot(df, aes(allowed, usage)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(alpha=0, method='lm') +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales='free_x', strip.position = 'bottom') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),       # remove x axis text
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),      # remove tick marks on x axis
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),      # remove title for axis
    strip.background = element_blank(),  # no box on facet label
    strip.placement = 'outside',         # facet label is outside axis line
    strip.text = element_text(size=12),
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'pt')      # remove space between facets
  )
p
```

[image]

The general idea is to consider that you kind of have 2 x axes here.  The primary axis by which you want to plot your points is `df$allowed`, whereas you then want to group based on `df$group`.  The easiest solution I can think of here was to treat each value of `df$group` as a separate facet, and then "stitch" the facets together by setting the space in-between them to zero.  Seems to work well.

The only comment here otherwise is that the boxes might be a bit too close together for your liking - making discrimination of the points of one group to be distinguished from another.  Since each group is a facet, and therefore a completely separate plot, you can "squish" the boxes together by adding/expanding the primary x axis for each facet like so:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(expand=expansion(mult=c(0.8)))
```

[image]

*Note: I had to remove a few super-high values in usage in order to be able to actually see your plots properly.  I imagine this is an artifact from copying over your data (like a missing value).*

Comment: This looks really promising thank you. Let me implement on the real data will respond back in a couple hours

Comment: This was good. I actually liked it w/o the faceting too, using the group aesthetic for all the geoms. It works both ways. For my exact data, the facet option was better because it made each group the same horizontal size. I had groups of 1-4 and groups of 2000-3000 so the version with variable sizes made those smaller ones just too narrow. If not for that, I would've preferred the non-faceted version.